# Interpreting random effects in lme4 package

Tags: r, random, mixed-models

I was dealing with the lme4 package in R and was a bit confused with how to interpret the random effects in a following example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lmerTest)
setwd("F:/5_1 Analize/Article_2 - LMM/")

dat <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:20, each = 60),
  Task = rep(1:60, each = 20),
  Group = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 20),
  Accuracy = sample(c(0,1), size = 1200, replace = T),
  RT = sample(200:3000, size = 1200, replace = T)
)

mod <- glmer(Accuracy~RT*Group + (1+RT|Task) + (1+RT|ID), data = dat, family = "binomial")
```

Basically every participant goes through 3 conditions (Group). In each conditions there are 20 trials (Task). We measure Accuracy and reaction time. In the modeling we want to predict Accuracy from RT, controlling for random effects in between subjects and tasks, both for intercepts and slopes. We also control for the fixed effect of the group.

The formula of the example can be described as:
`Accuracy ~ (beta0 + b0ID + b0Task + betaGroup0) + (beta1 + b1ID + b1Task + betaGroup1)*RT` (b-random effects, beta - fixed effects)

My question is following:

1) When i run `coef(mod)$ID` and look at the Intercept column - what do I see? Do I see random intercepts for each person across all three conditions, or do I see random intercepts for each person for Group A? My idea is the second one. If that is true, how can I get an average random person intercept for all three groups?

2) When I run `coef(mod)$Task` and also look at Intercept column - do I see intercepts for each item independantly of Group variable or not?

Thanks!

Comment: `coef(mod)$ID` is the random intercept corresponding to each of your 20 trials. Essentially the variation associated to each trial.

Comment: `coef(mod)$Task` is the random intercept corresponding to each task. The tasks might have different difficulty, so it might make sense to move this as a fixed effect, unless you think each task is the same and the variation is normally distributed around mean zero.

Comment: On top of all this, you have varying slopes based on `RT` for each `Task` and each trial (`ID`). By doing this you're assuming that `RT` has different effects on accuracy in each task and trial. You might want to assume that `RT` has the same slope in each trial (`ID`) since I assume it's the same conditions, just repeated 20 times. This would change your specification to `Accuracy~RT*Group + (1+RT|Task) + (1|ID)`

Comment: One final note: StackOverflow is typically for questions regarding code. Part of this question is related to interpreting statistical models and could be asked in the CrossValidated forum at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should I transfer the question to CrossValidated?

The ID is the subject code, it is not trial. And Task is each single trial a person goes through in the experiment (so there are 60 trials, and all of them are different. First 20 are in condition/group A, next 20 in condition B, and last 20 in group C...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, you should probably re-post on CrossValidated because it seems like the answer you're looking for is related to the model specification and not how to code or interpret code from R.